# Rspec-Watir; more elegant way of handling Material UI elements

Tags: rspec, watir-webdriver, material-ui

I am writing some automation code to change toggles in a Material UI component; however, I am running into issues interacting beyond opening the initial dialog.  Refer to HTML in image:
[image: mui-component]

The section highlighted in blue is where I need to drill down, but when I run an assertion like `p @browser.div(:class, 'mui-dialog-content').present?`, it returns `false`.  
I have tried the following:

1. Accessing it copying the xpath => this works!
2. Navigating through the DOM tree (i.e., `@browser.div.div.div.......(:class....)`

While using the xpath works, I am not a fan of how easily broken it is.

Any suggestions on how else I could interact with this element?

Comment: What do you get when you do `p @browser.divs(:class, 'mui-dialog-content').count`? That looks like a generic class name. If there are multiple, it is possible that you are looking at the wrong element. Watir returns the first match, where as you might want the second, third, etc.

Comment: Thanks @JustinKo, this sparked my thinking a little more--adding answer below

Answer (score 0):

Followed @JustinKo's suggestion of print a count of the # of `divs` with that class name.  There was only one.  I decided to take that info and try to navigate to it *directly*, and try to interact with the elements nested within 
It works!

I made the mistake of ASSuMing that, the class `mui-dialog-content` would only be navigable by drilling down into the structure from the parent `settings-dialog`.